# Cannot install Cocoapods on M1 Chip

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I am working on a Mac, M1 chip. I was working in React Native, when something happened with my system's configurations while trying to get the Android Build to work. No `npm`, `npx`, (any `node` commands really) worked, I couldn't do anything with my Pods, and essentially just everything was broken. I deleted and uninstalled everything to do with `Node`, `Java`, and `Cocoapods` but the issue I'm facing now is that I cannot install `CocoaPods`

I am following the directions from [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) and I am on my third try to just start a new React App. The Project will build, but I cannot install any pods and the whole app seems to not know that its supposed to be running off `React` as it won't let me use imported components.

So I have a plethora of issues in front of me, but the biggest is my inability to install CocoaPods.

I run...

```
brew install CocoaPods
```

and get the following return...

```
Warning: cocoapods 1.11.3 is already installed and up-to-date.
```

But upon running `npx react-native init` I get the following error...

```
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
```

So I tried as I was instructed, and attempted to run...

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Which gives me this...

```
make install failed, exit code 2
```

And since that fails, I cannot successfully run...

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

So it looks like my code is breaking before I can even type a single line. I've been trying to just create a new React Project for hours now... this seems very overly complicated

Comment: I had same issue, I installed  Cocoa Pods via gem install. For was the solution to uninstall Cocoa Pods und reinstall via brew

Answer (score 0):

Update your ruby to recent version, for that you can use `rbenv` via `homebrew`. After that install cocoapods via `gem install`

Answer (score 0):

There must have been some sort of corruption or only partially installed dependency. I ended up wiping my hard drive and restoring everything, it worked after that